# Getting errors in building image for raspberry pi3 (Yocto-Dunfell)

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, yocto

I’m trying to build the image for raspberry pi 3, but getting a few errors. I hope someone here will help me to solve it. I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox for this build. Run the below commands but get errors as outputs.(screenshots attached below)

```
    $ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping libsdl1.2-dev xterm
    $ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky -b dunfell
    $ cd poky
    $ git clone https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded -b dunfell
    $ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi -b dunfell
    $ source oe-init-build-env

    > I’m building the image for raspberry pi 3 so set the machine name to raspberrypi3 as : machine ?= "raspberrypi3" and commented other machine names in local.conf
    > To generate an SD card image file I’ve written IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.xz ext3 rpi-sdimg"
    > In bblayer.conf file I’ve added meta-raspberrypi layer path.

    $ bitbake core-minimal-image

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSwl8.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIOb6.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTlaU.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9aOU.png
```

Comment: Please paste the error contents via text instead, screenshots are not showing up

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a broken package. First things, try cleaning it and rebuilding

```
bitbake -c cleanall unzip  
bitbake -c cleanall binutils
bitbake unzip  
bitbake binutils
```

Also, do you actually need those packages? If not just remove them by adding to your local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = " unzip binutils "
```